# how to get the posts from my index page to someother pages(like blog) in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, indexing

i am beginner to WordPress, i have created the ***index.php*** it automatically shows my posts.. but i wanna posts to show also in another php file like ***blog.php***.. how can i retrieve the same posts which is shown in *index.php*.........

The scenario is, i am developing theme for http://themeforest.net show that i wanna make some features in my blog page like *without sidebar, left sidebar, right sidebar*... but my home(index.php) contains posts.. whenever i starts new page with same coding(like blog.php), it doesn't show the index.php 's posts..

Answer (score 1):

This sample piece of code retrieves 3 posts from categpry id 4

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'category' => 4 );
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
    $a= get_the_date();
    ?>

    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the WordPress documentation http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop
it contain different example how to display post include or exclude post from specific categories etc..